# req.file is undefined when i uploading photo using multer and cloudinary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer, cloudinary

so basically i creating an animal post api which have different field like name, type e.t.c and one of them is photo which i need to upload for this I am using multer and cloudinary but it give me error that "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')" when i try to figure out it, I find that req.file is undefined in animalController.js

```
index.js
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors';
import connectDB from "./mongodb/connect.js";
import userRouter from "./routes/userRoute.js";
import animalRouter from "./routes/animalRoute.js";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/v1/users", userRouter);
app.use("/api/v1/animals", animalRouter);

const startServer = async () => {
    try {
        connectDB(process.env.MONGODB_URL);

        app.listen(8080, () =>
            console.log("Server started on port http://localhost:8080"),
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
startServer();
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
animal.js
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import {addressSchema} from "./user.js"

const AnimalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim :true},
    type: {type: String, required:true, trim:true},
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    bread: {type: String},
    age: {type:Number, required: true},
    colour: {type:String, required:true},
    location: { type: addressSchema, required: true },
    date: { type:Date, default: Date.now, required:true },
    photo: { type: String, required: true },
    adopted: { type:Boolean, default: false, required: true},
    creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }
});

const animalModel = mongoose.model("Animal", AnimalSchema);

export default animalModel;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------



----------------------------------
authMiddleware.js
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import  jwt  from "jsonwebtoken";
import {body} from "express-validator";
import multer from "multer";

//Protected Routes token base
export const fetchUserId = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const decode =  jwt.verify(
        req.headers.authorization,
        process.env.JWT_SECRET
      );
      req.user = decode;
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).send({
        success: false,
        message: error.message,
      });
    }
  };

  export const validateRequest = (method) => {
    switch (method){
      case 'addAnimal': {
        return [
          body('name','name can not be null').notEmpty(),
          body('type','type can not be null').notEmpty(),
          body('description','name must be atleast 8 character').isLength({ min: 8 }),
          body('age','age must be number').isInt().notEmpty(),
          body('colour','colour can not be null').notEmpty(),
          body('photo','photo can not be null').notEmpty(),
        ]
      }
      case 'updateAnimal' : {
        return[
          body('description','name must be atleast 8 character').optional().isLength({ min: 8 }),
          body('age','age must be number').optional().isInt(),
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
  })
  export const upload = multer({storage:storage});
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
animalRoute.js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import express from "express";
import { addAnimal} from "../controllers/animalController.js";
import { fetchUserId ,validateRequest, upload} from "../middlewares/authMiddleware.js";

const router = express.Router();
//adding animal
router.post("/addAnimal",fetchUserId, upload.single('photo'), validateRequest('addAnimal'), addAnimal);
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



------------------------------------------------------
animalController.js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
import Animal from "../mongodb/models/animal.js";
import User from "../mongodb/models/user.js";

import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

//post adding animal detail
export const addAnimal = async(req,res) =>{
    try {
        const {name, type, description, bread, age, colour, location, adopted} = req.body;
        console.log(req.file);
        
        const photoUrl = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path,(err)=>{
            res.status(500).send({
                success:false,
                message:"error while uploading pic",
                error: err.message
            });
        });
        
        const newAnimal = await Animal.create({name, type, description, bread, age, colour, location, date, photo: photoUrl.url, adopted, creater: req.user._id});

        const user = await User.findOne(req.user._id);
        user.allAnimal.push(newAnimal._id);

        res.status(200).send({ success:true, message: "Animal added successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ success:false, message: error.message });
    }
};
--------------------------------------------------------


[![here u can see how i am sendinf data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyhlZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyhlZ.png)

[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERDyj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERDyj.png)
```

How can I upload imgage can, any any one correct the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the error you're facing, `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')"`, suggests that req.file is undefined, which means that the multer middleware is not properly handling the file upload. So there are some things you need to change in your current code.

In your `authMiddleware.js`, you've defined a storage configuration for multer. The destination should be a directory, not the original filename. Update the destination in the multer storage configuration:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './uploads'); 
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
```

With this, you should have the 'uploads' directory created in your project.

Secondly, in your `animalRoute.js`, you're using `upload.single('photo')`, which means the key in the FormData sent from the client should be named 'photo'. Ensure that when you're sending the data from the client, you're using the correct key for the image file.

Also, I have realized with time that it’s important to pay attention to complete error handling. You should check if the `cloudinary.uploader.upload` method is returning any errors. You can use a try-catch block around the `await cloudinary.uploader.upload` line or keep it simpler:

```
const photoUrl = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error uploading photo:", err);
        return res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Error while uploading pic",
            error: err.message
        });
    }
    return result;
});
```